# Как правильно апдейтить "вложенные" сущности

Tags: c#, mongodb

У меня есть сущность `ItemCategories` (в монго):

```
public class ItemCategory
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public Guid? ParentId { get; set; }
   public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

Так вот при отключении одной из категории все дочерние должны тоже отключаться. Я сделал это следующим образом (код несущественно изменен):

```
public async Task ChangeActivityAsync(ItemCategory item, bool active)
{
    item.IsActive = active;

    var items = await Repository.GetListAsync(x => x.ParentId == id);

    foreach (var parent in items)
    {
        await ChangeActivityAsync(parent, active);
    }

    item = await Repository.UpdateAsync(item);
}
```

Минусы данного подхода - очень частое обращение к бд. Можно ли это сделать проще? Проблема так же в том, что ItemCategory содержит в себе только лишь Id родителя, но не коллекцию вложенностей, поэтому структура получается плоская, а не древовидная.

Comment: Это так называемый Список Смежности - Adjacency List. Для работы с ним нужно использовать рекурсивные запросы. В SQL это реализуется с помощью CTE (если СУБД их поддерживает).

Comment: Я бы сохранял сразу всю пачку в БД, изменив им всем статус, а не по одной сущности. Но не зная, где и как вы делаете коммит, сложно конкретнее сказать. Ну и `race condition` возможны, так что может быть если БД прямо не страдает, то и оставить всё как есть.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov эх, к сожалению у меня не SQL, а Mongo

Comment: @CrazyElf бд не особо страдает, там дай бог 100 элементов(вообще в бд) наберется за всё время существования.. но для меня это не причина делать криво как сейчас

Comment: Ясно. В Монге есть [graphLookup](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov благодарю

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67104609/5045688